# Assigning to 'AppDelegate *' from incompatible type 'id<UIApplicationDelegate>'

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

In my project it says **Assigning to 'AppDelegate *' from incompatible type 'id'**.

What exactly is this? Why did this warning occur?

I have declared in .m

```
AppDelegate *appdev;
```

and in viewDidLoad

```
{
    appdev = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];     <= warning here
}
```

I want to hide this warning. What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just wonder because I do not get any warning with your code. Which Xcode version do you use?

Comment: I am sharing appdelegate to other viewcontroller for event handling. By importing #AppDelegate.h and declaring AppDelegate *xyz, I got this warning. Now I fixed it using below answers.Well, I am using latest Xcode 4.6.3

Comment: Strange, I do not get a warning if I do the same thing. Of course does an explicit type cast "fix" the warning, but I still wonder why this should be necessary for you and not for me. - Is the AppDelegate declared as `@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>` ?

Comment: Could it be that your AppDelegate is declared as `@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, SomeOtherProtocol>` ? - Then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147239/xcode-appdelegate-const-strong-to-parameter-of-incompatible-type-error would be the proper solution.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

since you know they equal, add a cast to let the compiler know

```
 AppDelegate* app = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

---

since this might come up in Swift too

```
 let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is the correct explanation. Assigning a `id<UIApplicationDelegate> objB` to an `AppDelegate *objA` does not generate a warning in my code (only the other way around). And actually I do not get a warning for the code from the question. There must be something else ...

Comment: The explicit cast should not be necessary. I assume that the AppDelegate is declared as conforming to an additional protocol, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147239/xcode-appdelegate-const-strong-to-parameter-of-incompatible-type-error.

Comment: Works prefect for me!

Answer (score 7):

If you want you have this for **import** **AppDelegate** **anywhere**. Is simple.

**IN APPDELEGATE**

```
/**
 *  Get AppDelegate
 *  Call [AppDelegate getAppDelegate]
 *
 *  @return AppDelegate
 */
+ (AppDelegate *) app {
    return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

**ANYWHERE IN YOUR CLASS**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h" // TOP OF YOUR CLASS

AppDelegate *app = [AppDelegate app];
```

Comment: in objC and also swift, you'd SO NOT name a getter 'getXY'

Comment: @Daij-Djan i have change my response

Answer (score 3):

You can type-cast it to prevent the warning message.

try:

```
appdev = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to type cast because it returns Protocol.

```
appdev = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```